# generate new group containing one value from each of n other groups

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Given the below example data:

```
test_data <- tibble(
  FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE = c(rep("Father", times = 2), rep("Mother", times = 2), 
                         rep("Daugther", times = 3), rep("Son", times = 3)),
  NAME = c("Fred", "Frank", "Mary", "Megan", "Diane", "Denise", "Daisy", 
           "Sam", "Scott", "Steve"))
```

How would one go about creating a new grouping variable, FAMILY_NUMBER, which shows the possible combination of families, given only one FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE can be in a family.

I.e. An example of the desired output (with 2 possible families):

```
output_data <- tibble(
   FAMILY_NUMBER = c(rep("FAMILY 1", 4), rep("FAMILY 2", 4)),
   NAME = c("Fred", "Mary", "Diane", "Sam", "Fred", "Megan", "Diane","Sam"),
   FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE = c(rep(c("Father", "Mother", "Daughter", "Son"), 2)))

    > output_data
    # A tibble: 8 x 3
      FAMILY_NUMBER NAME  FAMILY_MEMBER
      <chr>         <chr> <chr>        
    1 FAMILY 1      Fred  Father       
    2 FAMILY 1      Mary  Mother       
    3 FAMILY 1      Diane Daughter     
    4 FAMILY 1      Sam   Son          
    5 FAMILY 2      Fred  Father       
    6 FAMILY 2      Megan Mother       
    7 FAMILY 2      Diane Daughter     
    8 FAMILY 2      Sam   Son
```

EDIT: I've changed the `test_data` to contain unequal numbers of FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE, since in the practical case I need to apply this solution to, the groups contain unequal numbers of variables.

Comment: Check `expand.grid`: `expand.grid(split(test_data$NAME, test_data$FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE))`

Comment: Thanks Henrik, this seems to work. Too bad the vector I want to output with my actual data is 5791818.1Gb :/

Answer (score 0):

If the number of members is equal and known, you can simply add sequential numbers to each of them.

```
test_data <- tibble(
  FAMILY_MEMBER_TYPE = c(rep("Father", times = 3), rep("Mother", times = 3), 
                         rep("Daugther", times = 3), rep("Son", times = 3)),
  NAME = c("Fred", "Frank", "Felix", "Mary", "Megan", "Michelle", "Diane", 
           "Denise", "Daisy", "Sam", "Scott", "Steve")) 

test_data$family <- seq(1, 3)

arrange(test_data, family)
```

Comment: Unfortunately in the practical case I need to apply this solution to, all groups do not have the same number of variables, so I need something a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Like a sequential count of each family member?

Comment: Not exactly. Henrik's code gives the desired output. But thanks for your help!